# Recommended way to transform map after using groupBy in Scala?

Tags: scala

I have a Java enum being used from a dependency, and want to create a map from it.

Let's say the enum is called "SomeEnum1":

```
BLUE(SomeEnum1.builder()
    .someOtherIdentifier("ABC")
    .someImportantField("DEF")), ...
RED( //etc
```

I am able to use groupby and get a Map from the "someImportantField" value to a list of SomeEnum1:

```
SomeEnum1.values.groupBy(x => x.someImportantField)
```

But upon doing this, I get a Map[String, Array[SomeEnum1]] when what I want is a Map[String, Array[String]]. I've tried using:

```
SomeEnum1.values.groupBy(_.getSomeImportantField).mapValues(_.name)
```

But I get an error that name does not a member of Array[....SomeEnum1].
Is there some other way I can transform the resulting arrays to contain the enum names instead of the enum itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a loop:

```
SomeEnum1.values.groupBy(_.getSomeImportantField).mapValues(_.map(_.name))
```

`mapValues` iterates over each Map value, which is an array of enums. For each of these arrays you want to convert each element to a String.